# Python RPM package generation fails with 'rpm: -ba: unknown option' - rpmbuild is available

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpm, rpmbuild, python-packaging

My issue is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15774549/1796). But it differs in a few key points and the solution over there does not work.

**I have a simple Python 3 project with a package containing a few simple classes. I need to package this project as an RPM and publish it on a private repo.**

Environment:

```
Mac OS X 10.15.3 (Catalina)
Python 3.7.3
rpm 4.15.1

Package           Version
----------------- -------
astroid           2.3.3  
coverage          5.0.4  
isort             4.3.21 
lazy-object-proxy 1.4.3  
mccabe            0.6.1  
pip               20.0.2 
pylint            2.4.4  
setuptools        46.1.3 
six               1.12.0 
typed-ast         1.4.1  
wheel             0.34.2 
wrapt             1.11.2
```

I have a setup.py file in the project root:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:  # README.md exists alongside, is readable and has few ASCII text
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="my_util",
    version="0.2.0",
    author="Andrei Rinea",
    author_email="my@email.com",
    description="Utils",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://example.com/",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "License :: Other/Proprietary License"
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.7',
    license='(C) ACME Example 2020',
    platforms='any'
)
```

When I run

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm
```

I end up having an error:

```
... (successfully making directories, copying files etc.)
...
copying dist/my_util-0.2.0.tar.gz -> build/bdist.macosx-10.15-x86_64/rpm/SOURCES
building RPMs
rpm -ba --define _topdir /Users/andrei/Work/my-util/build/bdist.macosx-10.15-x86_64/rpm --clean build/bdist.macosx-10.15-x86_64/rpm/SPECS/my_util.spec
rpm: -ba: unknown option
error: command 'rpm' failed with exit status 1
```

`rpmbuild` is available in path:

```
% rpmbuild --version

RPM version 4.15.1
```

I searched all over Google but there aren't many results, the closest being the Stackoverflow question linked at the beginning. That one is on Linux, and it seems that installing rpm-build (which seems to be included with rpm on OS X) for that guy worked.

**LATER EDIT**: Distutils version:

```
% python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Nov 15 2019, 04:04:52) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import distutils
>>> print (distutils.__version__)
3.7.3
```

Comment: A good place to start is reading https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/command/bdist_rpm.py, which is the code actually calling `rpmbuild` (or, in your case, apparently `rpm`).

Comment: ..note that in the master branch of distutils (linked above), it no longer has any codepath that starts `rpm` at all, and *only* runs `rpmbuild`. Which version of `distutils` are you running?

Comment: thanks for the useful hints! How can I tell the version of `distutils`? it doesn't get listed in `pip list`, where should I look?

Comment: OS X came with Python 2.7.16 and then I installed `pyenv` and used that to install Python 3.7.7

Comment: `import distutils; print distutils.__version__`, in the repl for the Python interpreter you're using to run `setup.py`.

Comment: That said, MacOS is not exactly a common and well-supported platform for rpm.

Comment: Thanks again! I added a LATER EDIT section at the bottom of the question showing how I got the distutils version of 3.7.3

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to be able to write an answer; thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that distutils 3.7.3 only uses `rpmbuild` if it's found in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, as you can see [in its source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/distutils/command/bdist_rpm.py#L312-L315):

```py
rpm_cmd = ['rpm']
if os.path.exists('/usr/bin/rpmbuild') or \
   os.path.exists('/bin/rpmbuild'):
    rpm_cmd = ['rpmbuild']
```

If you can symlink it into that position, that's probably your easiest answer. Otherwise, you may need to patch your copy of `bdist_rpm.py`.

Comment: Wow, indeed. SIP on OS X won't let me symlink it even with `sudo`. I'd rather patch my copy o `bdist_rpm` or upgrading to another version of Python.